# How can one both be able to use IntelliJ to manage a project's configuration and yet also have a VCS repository with none of IntelliJ's metadata?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I have two things that I want to do that seem like they are in conflict with each other.  On the one hand, I would like to use IntelliJ's GUI interface to manage my project's configuration and so I would like to put the metadata in its version-controlled repository.  On the other hand, I want the result of my work to be a repository that does not require the end-user to have IntelliJ, so I not only want there to be no metadata in the repository I publish, but in its place I want to have files that provide some standard Java build system in their place.  Is there a convenient way to let me have both of these things?

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ lets you use tools like Ant or Maven for its builds, and provides a nice GUI for interfacing with them. And anyone without the tool can just use Ant or Maven to run the builds from the command line. You'll either have a build.xml (for Ant) or a pom.xml (for Maven) as part of your source tree.

If you're not going to check in the Intellij project configuration, I recommend setting up a configuration-directory-based project then just set up your version control to ignore the .idea directory. Personally, I consider my project configuration to practically be source code, so I tend to check in everything except my .idea/workspace.xml file. As long as I'm using Ant or Maven to do the builds, people without IntelliJ can still build the project fine.

Comment: Cool, so in other words having two parallel sets of build configurations in the repository is fine because it is not a big deal for people using the project to just ignore the .idea files.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, generally I use the Maven or Ant build as my "official" build / deploy script. Anything IntelliJ builds is strictly for development & automated testing.